# Grails Login Not Working

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I am using Grails 2.4 with spring security

```
       compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"
```

The following is my bootstrap.groovy

```
   import com.aarestu.grailstest.Role
  import com.aarestu.grailstest.User
  import com.aarestu.grailstest.UserRole
   class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->


    def user = new User(usernmae: 'user', password: 'user').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    def userSecond = new User(usernmae: 'user2', password: 'user').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    def admin = new User(usernmae: 'admin', password: 'admin').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)



    def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    new UserRole(user: user, role: userRole).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    new UserRole(user: admin, role: adminRole).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

}
def destroy = {
}
```

}

It created 2 entries into the table Role but none of the others.
I then manually created a user in the database and when I try to login with the user it simply doesnt work even though I can view it in the database.

If the

```
         failOnError:true
```

Is not included then it runs ok but I cannot login, if it is included I get the error included at the very end

I also accounted for the double encoding by modifying my USER controller to include the following

```
  boolean beforeInsertRunOnce = false
boolean beforeUpdateRunOnce = false
Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this)*.role
}
def beforeInsert() {
    if (! beforeInsertRunOnce) {
        beforeInsertRunOnce = true
        encodePassword()
    }
}
def afterInsert() {
    beforeInsertRunOnce = false
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password') && ! beforeUpdateRunOnce ) {
        beforeUpdateRunOnce = true
        encodePassword()
    }
}
def afterUpdate() {
    beforeUpdateRunOnce = false
}
```

Error

```
   Error |
2016-02-09 11:42:58,434 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR  context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application:   Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
      - Field error in object 'com.aarestu.grailstest.User' on field 'username': rejected value [null]; codes    [com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable.error.com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username,com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable.error.username,com   .aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable.error.java.lang.String,com.aarestu .grailstest.User.username.nullable.error,user.username.nullable.error.com.aar estu.grailstest.User.username,user.username.nullable.error.username,user.user name.nullable.error.java.lang.String,user.username.nullable.error,com.aarestu .grailstest.User.username.nullable.com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username,com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable.username,com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable.java.lang.String,com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable,user.username.nullable.com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username,user.username.nullable.username,user.username.nullable.java.lang.String,user.username.nullable,nullable.com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username,nullable.username,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [username,class com.aarestu.grailstest.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
Message: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'com.aarestu.grailstest.User' on field 'username': rejected value [null]; codes  [com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable.error.com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username,com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable.error.username,com  .aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable.error.java.lang.String,com.aarestu .grailstest.User.username.nullable.error,user.username.nullable.error.com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username,user.username.nullable.error.username,user.username.nullable.error.java.lang.String,user.username.nullable.error,com.aarestu .grailstest.User.username.nullable.com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username,com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable.username,com.aarestu.grailstest.User .username.nullable.java.lang.String,com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username.nullable,user.username.nullable.com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username,user.username.nullable.username,user.username.nullable.java.lang.String,user.username.nullable,nullable.com.aarestu.grailstest.User.username,nullable.username,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [username,class com.aarestu.grailstest.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}]  cannot be null]
 Line | Method
  ->>    9 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
```

---

```
 |    327 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
 |     320 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
 |    296 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
 |    266 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
 |   1142 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
 |    617 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
 ^    745 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
 Error |
 Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Any help or point in the right direction would be much appreciated

Comment: The reason why you cannot login when failOnError is present is that adding failOnError: true will throw an exception when there is a problem while saving the instance and the application will not start because of this Exception. Therefore, when failOnError: true is not present, even if any instance is invaild or cannot be saved, the app will continue working normally. To sum it up, your instances where never saved to DB, so you cannot log in.

Answer (score 0):

The bootsrap.groovy code was wrong

This following needs to be changed from

```
       def user = new User(usernmae: 'user', password: 'user').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        def admin = new User(usernmae: 'admin', password: 'admin').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
   Role(user: user, role: userRole).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    new UserRole(user: admin, role: adminRole).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

to

```
         def user = new User(username: 'user', password: 'password', enabled: true).save()
        def admin = new User(username: 'admin', password: 'password', enabled: true).save()
        UserRole.create user, roleUser
        UserRole.create admin, roleUser
        UserRole.create admin, roleAdmin, true
```